# How to split xml nodes into separate nodes?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML like,

```
<bank>
     <employee>
              <name>ABC</name>
              <ID>123</ID>
     </employee>
     <employee>
              <name>DEF</name>
              <ID>123</ID>
     </employee>
</bank>
```

I want to split my XML into two separate nodes based on the tag  i.e, for each `<name>` to be unique, the XML should be split up as

```
<bank>
         <employee>
                  <name>ABC</name>
                  <ID>123</ID>
         </employee>
</bank>
<bank>
         <employee>
                  <name>DEF</name>
                  <ID>123</ID>
         </employee>
</bank>
```

How can it be done in DOM parser using java? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have multiple root nodes in XML, which is not allowed by standard.

```
public static void transform(Element bankNode, Element targetNode) {
    NodeList employees = bankNode.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < employees.getLength(); i++) {
        Element newBankNode = targetNode.getOwnerDocument().createElement(bankNode.getNodeName());
        targetNode.appendChild(newBankNode);

        newBankNode.appendChild(targetNode.getOwnerDocument().importNode(employees.item(i), true));
    }
}
```